# Summing elements within an eval statement, in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, eval

I have written a complete code that runs in MATLAB, but outputs a slightly incorrect result. I need to get the following:

```
utotal
```

where

```
utotal = S1plot + S2plot + ...
```

until the digit equals (N/2) + 1, where N is even. If N = 10, say, the digit would be 6.

Then I need to evaluate utotal within the script. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far:

```
N = 10;
for alpha = 1:(N/2+1)
    eval(['utotal = sum(S' num2str(alpha) 'plot);'])
end
```

but it doesn't work because it evaluates the following:

```
utotal = sum(S1plot);
utotal = sum(S2plot);
utotal = sum(S3plot);
utotal = sum(S4plot);
utotal = sum(S5plot);
utotal = sum(S6plot);
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: If `N=3` then `(N/2)+1=2.5`, what digit does that correspond to? Using `eval` is often a sign that your code could be improved. For example, do you have to use `S1plot`, `S2plot` etc as your variable names? Using a matrix or cell array would make this question almost trivial.

Comment: Why would you do this? Why would you not simply put all of your `S*plot` variables in a an array: `Splot(1), Splot(2), Splot(3),...` and then use `sum(Splot))`?

Comment: Edited: N is even. I am really on the verge of completing my project, and I have used eval statements everywhere, so I am trying to use that here.

Comment: Are `S1plot`, `S2plot`, ... scalars?

Comment: @beaker No, they are matrices.

Comment: dimensions would be useful

Comment: @beaker Sorry - Each S*plot is 51-by-5, and I need to plot(K00,utot), where K00 is 1-by-51.

Comment: For future reference anyway, `eval` is poor Matlab programming practice, and there almost always exists a faster, more efficient and easy to read alternative.

Comment: @David I agree wholeheartedly. Think I'll add a disclaimer to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround you can use for now. Note that this is extremely bad coding practice and the difficulty you're having now is only one of the reasons you shouldn't do it.

```
%// Generate random data
S1plot = randi(100,51,5);
S2plot = randi(100,51,5);
S3plot = randi(100,51,5);
S4plot = randi(100,51,5);
S5plot = randi(100,51,5);
S6plot = randi(100,51,5);
N = 10;

%// Put individual matrices into 3D matrix S
%// To access matrix Snplot, use S(:,:,n)
%// This is the format these variables should have been in in the first place
for alpha = 1:(N/2+1)
    eval(['S(:,:,' num2str(alpha) ') = (S' num2str(alpha) 'plot);'])
end

%// Now sum along the third dimension
utotal = sum(S,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

> See the comments by @beaker. This solution does not do what the OP wants.

I haven't tested this but it should work.

```
N=10;
for alpha = 1:(N/2+1)
    allSum = [allSum 'sum(S' num2str(alpha) 'plot)+'];
end

allSum(end)=';';
eval(['utotal = ' allSum]);
```

Comment: This will give you `sum(S6plot)+sum(S5plot)+...+sum(S1plot);`, correct? This will sum the columns of each individual `S*plot` matrix into a row vector and then sum all the row vectors. I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Actually, it's `sum(S1plot)+sum(S2plot)+sum(S3plot)+sum(S4plot)+sum(S5plot)+sum(S6plot)+;` and you need to initialize `allSum = [];`

Comment: @beaker Yes, you are correct about your first comment. However, I am replacing the last `+` sign by `;`, so after `sum(S6Plot)`, there will be no `+` sign. I will let the answer stay but add a note saying it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 10;
Result =0;
for alpha = 1:(N/2+1)
   Result = Result + num2str(alpha)
end
eval(['utotal = sum(S' Result 'plot);'])
```

Comment: Wont this just evaluate `utotal=sum(S309plot);`? Which I don't think is what OP wants at all.